Flutter and Git are being deleted when running 'flutter pub get' in VS Code, why?
Background: I recently set up flutter on my machine for a new part time position, and while encountering issues in Android Studio, I migrated to VS Code. However, after a successful install of flutter to C:\Users\name\dev, and verifying git installation, when I open a project in VS Code, flutter pub get --no-example will run, and when I try to run flutter doctor or any flutter command, I get "Unable to find git in PATH' or something along the lines of "unable to find sdk in [sdk path]". I will then try a git --version, which will respond by saying git is not a recognized command. I reinstall both, it works, and then randomly that above process will repeat, typically when I close and reopen VS Code.
I have verified PATH variables before and after this happens, and nothing changes in my environment variables. I've tried sifting through VS Code settings but have been unable to locate anything there. Ultimately, this keeps happening and in the middle of programming I will have to go through the reinstall process over and over. I am wondering if this is being caused by VS Code in some way or something with my system environment.

what does "flutter doctor -v" say?

Why don't you try install Flutter directly from your VS Code? Also, download it directly there. Here's the documentation about it, Install Flutter.

So that's the issue. I run it once, like it did today, it tells me it can't find git, (because somehow git was uninstalled between the time I ran flutter doctor), and then it just tells me. '"C:\Users\adamc\dev\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
It exists where that file location it is, and everything is indeed correct in PATH. I'm just at a total loss.
